# Spring SpEL chooses wrong method to invoke

Tags: spring, java, spring-el

I'm trying to evaluate the following SpEL expression (Spring-expression version 3.1.1):

```
T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).newArrayList(#iterable)
```

where #iterable is of type java.lang.Iterable.
Google Guava com.google.common.collect.Lists (version 14.0) does have a method *newArrayList(Iterable)* but for some reason SpEL chooses to invoke a different method: *newArrayList(Object[])*

I dived into the code and found the issue to be with **org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodResolver** implementation: it seems to be sensitive to the manner in which methods are sorted by the java.lang.Class::getMethods. 
If 2 methods match the invocation (in the case one of the methods is varargs), the later method (in the order) will be invoked, instead of choosing the method that isn't varargs (which is more specific). 
It seems like JDK doesn't guarantee the order the methods are sorted: different runs show different order.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Send a patch implementing the correct behavior to the developers of Spring?

Comment: As a workaround I can suggest introduce your own `util` class with the delegation to that Guava method. In meantime you can open a JIRA issue on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection projections of Spring EL to select all from iterable and convert it to list:

```
"#iterable.?[true]"
```

A simple example to test:

```
Iterable<Integer> it = () -> new Iterator<Integer>() {

  private int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
  private int index = 0;

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return index < a.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer next() {
    return a[index++];
  }
};
Tmp tmp = new Tmp();
tmp.setO(it);
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(tmp);

ArrayList<Integer> list = parser.parseExpression("o.?[true]").getValue(context,
    ArrayList.class);
```